# Where are XSD type abbreviations defined

Tags: types, xsd

I am trying to understand an XSD file with the following element

```
<xs:element name="Number" type="an..80M"/>
```

I am familiar with simple types like string, date, boolean, decimal, etc.  And I am familiar with complex types that are defined inside the XSD or in imported XSDs.

But what is **"an..80M"**?  And where can I find the definition of these abbreviations (if that is even the right terminology)?

The XSD file starts with this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.surescripts.com/messaging" 
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 targetNamespace="http://www.surescripts.com/messaging" 
 elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

So I don't think this could be defined in an external schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are custom types defined by your schema provider. Those aren't standard data types. So check the imported or included schema.

Comment: You are correct.

The schema includes this definition.  Just missed it the first time thru.
 <xs:simpleType name="an..80M">
  <xs:restriction base="anM">
   <xs:maxLength value="80"/>
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>